# Saving quiz info while using AJAX in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cookies

I am creating a quiz and I am not quite sure what the best practice would be to save quiz sessions.

Right now I have a quiz database where users can select multiple categories of questions that they want to use.

i.e.

```
id question        answer   volume
1  "Generic Quest" "Answer" 1
1  "Generic Quest" "Answer" 2
1  "Generic Quest" "Answer" 1
```

So for instance a user will be able to select questions from multiple volumes of questions or just a single volume prior to starting the quiz.

What I would like to know is what is the best way to store which questions are selected while the quiz is in progress. I am trying to have the questions asked one at a time and I am trying to learn more about AJAX to transition between questions. When a user answers a question I would like to have a score that updates as each question is answered and move on to the next question randomly. If a user starts a quiz that has 500 questions, how can I temporarily store which questions they are going to be asked and when one is asked I can just remove it.

I am learning more about cookies, and as a ballpark guess, would I be able to have a cookie or session store the questions remaining in the quiz and when it is answered just remove it. I feel like that is clearly not the answer but I can't think of what the best way to go about that would be. I am trying to avoid a request response structure for better user experience, and my own personal learning goals, but feel free to chime in if you feel like it would work better.

EDIT:

Here is my impression so far from the comments:

Questions Table

```
id question        answer   volume
1  "Generic Quest" "Answer" 1
2  "Generic Quest" "Answer" 2
3  "Generic Quest" "Answer" 1
4  "Generic Quest" "Answer" 3
```

Users Table

```
id username        
1  "User A" 
2  "User B"
3  "User C"
```

Quizzes Table (Here is where I am wondering how I should implement it) My impression is that when a user starts a quiz it would create a new entry into this table with the information of the quiz)

```
id user_id   question_id
1  2         [%w 1 3 2 ]
2  1         [%w 3 2 4] 
3  3         [%w 1 3]
```

The reason I was leaning towards this from the comments was because there are three categories of questions (volumes) a user can choose from. Each volume has a list of 100-300 questions, but a user can choose more than one volume to add to the quiz. If there was an array of the questions that are all listed in the single table when it is answered it can be removed from the question_id array. The question_id array would obviously not be directly associated within the modules to the questions, but when calling on the next question it could find(question_id). Was this anything like you were talking about trh?

Comment: 500 questions is probably too many for reliable cookie or browser session data, using ajax to get and fetch from a db store is probably more stable.  So a users_quizzes table could have a user_id and a quiz_id and a question_id and a score - then you'd always know which question came next so you would need 3 models in that case

Comment: in that case, if I had 500 questions, would I have the question_id be an array of all the questions ids within the quizzes table? So if a user creates a quiz, so now user_id 1 just started quiz_id 1 that stores the selected questions_id in an array that can be used to randomize and remove after the question has been asked. Would this be a valid approach?

Comment: I would probably make each question_id be individual, and a quick ajax update after each question is either created or answered - and then a method on the Quiz model to choose a random question from available ones for that user

Comment: Edited the question to show what I was thinking after your initial comment. I was wondering because the way that you are explaining sounds like when a user starts a quiz with 500 questions, 500 new entries into the quiz table are made. I was wonder how optimal this would be.

Comment: Kind of depends on how long it takes to answer a question. It also depends on whether a quiz is  more like a recipe, or complete unique.  Recipe style would be if iyou have a collection of items, and a user chooses which ones will belong in his quiz - in that case, perhaps a JSON data field would be a good way to store them i the quiz, then you can additionally store in that json object the status (whether or not the user has seen the item) -- but even then you are still updating the database each time  question is answered

Comment: The quiz isn't super complicated. Expected to take a second or two to answer. Sorry I didn't even think of how complicated quizzes can be. It's 2 or four questions multiple choice, so they will just be buttons a users selects.

Comment: For 2 or 4 questions , even up to 10, I would store them in a json field in the db along with the score and status -- I wouldn't update the datbase until a user has completed a quiz, and store each update in the session until it's complete

Comment: My mistake, 2 or 4 possible answers. There is going to be 500+ questions per quiz

Comment: That starts to get very tricky - I might in that case go with a question model, belonging to a quiz, and a user_question model which saves on a periodic basis based on the data stored in session - so they answer questions, each answer writes to session as it's presented- question id and score -- after 20 or so questions, or 60 browser seconds, then an ajax push to the database to update user_questions.  With that many questions, you need some happy medium between few database hits and also accuracy of user progress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108580/discussion-between-joe-marion-and-trh).